# Understanding JDBC Timeout Variables and replication

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, replication, database-replication

I am using JDBC driver to connect to mySql from my java code (read client).

```
Driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
JdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://<<IpOftheDb>>/<<DbSchema Name>>?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeout=5000&socketTimeout=10000
```

In case the database is down ( machine hosting the db is up but the mysqld process is not running) , it takes some time to get the exception , The exception is

**"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."**

In the statement above socketTimeout is 10 sec . Now if I bring up the db with 10 sec as SocketTimeout I get the response correctly.

But If i reduce it to one sec and am executing the query I get the same exception.

**"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."**

But connectTimeout doesnt change anything. Can someone explain me what socketTimeout and connectTimeout means.

Also , If we are setting up replication and specifying the 2nd database as failover i.e.

my connection string changes to

```
jdbc:mysql://<<PrimaryDbIP>>,<<SecondaryDbIp>>/<<DbSchema>>?useTimezone=true
&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
    &failOverReadOnly=false&autoReconnect=true&maxReconnects=3
    &initialTimeout=5000&connectTimeout=6000&socketTimeout=6000
    &queriesBeforeRetryMaster=50&secondsBeforeRetryMaster=30
```

I see that if primary is down then I get the response from secondary (failover Db) .
Now when client executes a query , does it go to primary database and then wait for socketTimeout (or whatever) and then goes to Secondary or it goes to Seconday before timeout occurs.
Moreover, the second time when the same connection Object is used , does it go directly to the secondary or again the above process is repeated .

I tried find some documentation which explains this but couldnt get .

Hopefully , someone can help here explaining the various timeout parameters and their usefulness.

Comment: You should be looking at the MySQL reference manual for the replication stuff, and the JDBC documentation for the JDBC stuff.

Comment: thanks EJP , I did looked into those but could not understand it correctly there :(( .I am looking for some explanation here to understand it better .